# 3D Plotting: How do I rotate the camera's view about the ViewVector?

Tags: plotting

I specified a ViewVector, but now the plot is appearing upside down. I want this:

[image]

to become this:

[image]

How can I change that angle?

**The code:**

```
In[15]:= viewcent = {avgX, avgY, avgZ}

Out[15]= {-24.1665, -5.73778, 783.169}

In[16]:= viewpt = {{-avgX - 700, -avgY - 700, avgZ - 400}, viewcent}

Out[16]= {{-675.834, -694.262, 383.169}, {-24.1665, -5.73778, 783.169}}

In[17]:= ListPointPlot3D[data2, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Ticks -> Automatic, ViewVector -> viewpt,
  ViewAngle -> All, 
 PlotRange ->  
  All ]
```

Comment: People will be much more willing to work on your problem if you were to provide the code that produced the images you show.

Comment: Perhaps [`ViewVertical`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewVertical.html) is what you're looking for?